# Mysql Select across multiple tables with joins

Tags: mysql

I have a number of tables to store different product types in my database (these products have overlapping columns but also some columns unique to the product).  Products are associated with a manufacturer (whose details are stored in their own table), and a category.  I need to work out a select statement that will get all products from the multiple tables along with the manufacturer details and category details (so I can display the long form manufacturer and category names).  Example tables below:

```
product_table1:
  product_id,
  manufacturer_id,
  category_id,
  product_name,
  ...

product_table2:
  product_id,
  manufacturer_id,
  category_id,
  product_name,
  ...

category_table:
  category_id,
  category_name
  ...

manufacturer_table:
  manufacturer_id,
  manufacturer_name
  ...
```

I need to get (with rows from all product tables):

```
manufacturer_id,
  category_id,
  product_name,
  ... other product columns common to all product tables
  ... I can hard code these if necessary, they don't have 
  ... to be worked out
  manufacturer_name,
  category_name
```

I'm willing to consider schema changes although it's not an option to store all products in a single table (there would just be too many columns, while MySQL could handle it, maintaining and understand it would become difficult).

I know I could do this with multiple selects but I would really like to not do that.  Also, it's not an option to pull out the common columns into their own table.  There are other levels of complexity that are introduced by that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, though it may have efficiency issues:

```
SELECT all_products.manufacturer_id, all_products.category_id, all_products.product_name, manufacturer.manufacturer_name, category.category_name
FROM manufacturer
JOIN
(
 SELECT manufacturer_id, category_id, product_name
 FROM product_table1
 UNION ALL
 SELECT manufacturer_id, category_id, product_name
 FROM product_table2
) AS all_products ON all_products.manufacturer_id = manufacturer.manufacturer_id
JOIN category ON category.category_id = all_products.category_id
```

Comment: This works but as it's for an admin interface we decided to force users to select a product group to keep the code complexity down.  Thanks all the same, I'll remember it for the future.